# CameraX: Unable to check if extension is available or not

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I am trying to check whether a given extension is available or not while adding tabs to my TabLayout but there seems to be some serious issue here (or maybe I'm unaware of something).

```
extensionsManager.isExtensionAvailable((CameraProvider)cameraProvider, cameraSelector, ExtensionMode.NIGHT);
```

This code would have worked if `ProcessCameraProvider` was a subtype of `CameraProvider`, which according to Android Studio doesn't seem to be the case.

[image]

Also, the code snippet here shouldn't work if `ProcessCameraProvider` isn't a subtype of `CameraProvider`. (https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/vendor-extensions#enable-effect-capture)

Am I not aware of something or am I referring the wrong instance...Could someone please help me with out with this issue?

Here are all the camerax extension I am using along with their version number.

[image]

Comment: Why do you cast the `ProcessCameraProvider` to `CameraProvider`? there is no need to do so. As far as I know using the `ProcessCameraProvider` object without casting it to a  `CameraProvider` works just fine.

Comment: Not really, currently (in the library code on inspecting) `ProcessCameraProvider` does not implement the `CameraProvider` interface. The casting was done to just show that error. Without that, Android Studio just says that an instance of `CameraProvider` is required.

Comment: This is I obtained the instance of the `ProcessCameraProvider`: `val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()`, and then when checking for the extension availability I just use this object and it works just fine, no error.

Comment: That's strange... Maybe it's an issue only with the Java side of the library

Comment: Try [this link](https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/WKUERN9U2fo). I suggest you contact the developers - email in the link, and ask them about that, they reply quickly.

Comment: I have filed an issue on GitHub regarding the same. https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/413

Answer (score 1):

[`ProcessCameraProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/lifecycle/ProcessCameraProvider) is in fact a subtype of [`CameraProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraProvider) (which you can notice from the documentation). This has been the case I believe starting from version `1.1.0-alpha02`.

Make sure you're using the right version of the libraries, namely `camera-camera2` and `camera-lifecycle`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have added the version numbers of each extension used in the project (related to CameraX) in the form of an image at the end of the question's description. I'm trying to stick to stable as far as possible. Could you please help me with the version numbers in your answer? Thanks in advance

Comment: I had filed an issue on GitHub regarding the same. https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/413